# Problemas con dockerfile y laravel

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

Tengo el siguiente dockerfile

```
FROM composer:latest AS composer

# continue with the official PHP image
FROM php:7.2-fpm-stretch

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    supervisor \
    nginx \
    zip

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

ADD docker/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
ADD docker/virtualhost.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
ADD docker/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

COPY --chown=root:www-data . /var/www/html/app

# copy the Composer PHAR from the Composer image into the PHP image
COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

WORKDIR /var/www/html/app

COPY ./.env.local .env

RUN chmod -R g+w /var/www/html/app/storage
RUN chmod -R g+w /var/www/html/app/bootstrap
RUN composer install
RUN php artisan key:generate

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

y en mi proyecto de Larvel tengo un .env.local y hay dos cosas que no funcionan:

1) No copia el .env.local a .env 
2) No aparece la carpeta vendor, por mas que corrio el composer install correctamente!

Comment: ¿Por que no pasas las variables de entorno cuando ejecutas el contenedor? Asi no tendras "hardcode" las variables dentro del contenedor.

Respecto al compose install... no te sabria decir. ¿Te termina correctamente todo el build de la imagen?

Comment: Termina perfecto todo el build, pero no aparece la carpeta vendor ni copia el .env.

Vos decis en el dockerfile agregar variabbles de entorno?

Comment: ¿Cual es el comando exacto con el que ejecutas el contenedor?

Lo que yo digo es pasarle las variables de entorno cuando ejecutas el contendor. Esto te dara mayor flexibilidad.